# 3 Table Join with Clause appearing null values

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have 3 tables regarding a supermarket chain:
Stores (where I have store ID and city)
Customers (where I have cust. ID)
and
Purchases (where I have the store ID, Cust ID and quantity purchased by each customer).

I want to list the total value of purchases per client that purchase in a given city's stores but the listing should include all client names.

I  tried to make it as below:

```
SELECT customers.cname, SUM(purchases.quantity)
FROM stores LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON stores.SID = purchases.Stores AND stores.city     = 'Porto'
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.CID = purchases.cust
GROUP BY customers.cname;
```

However this returns just the customers that have purchased in said city, not the ones that haven't.

How should I solve this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

```
CNAME          SUM(PURCHASES.QUANTITY)
Abel Antunes    3
Berta Borges    13
Carlos Caldas   6
Daniela Dimas   3
Elvira Elvas    14
```

The result above is what the table looks like using your example (Filipe Silva)

Executing the following statement:

```
SELECT customers.cname, SUM(purchases.quantity)
FROM stores LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON stores.SID = purchases.Stores AND stores.city = 'Porto'
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.CID = purchases.cust
GROUP BY customers.cname;
```

Results in the following table:

```
CNAME   SUM(PURCHASES.QUANTITY)
(null)  (null)
Abel Antunes    1
Berta Borges    5
Daniela Dimas   2
```

Which represent the correct values, but is missing the rest of the customer list.
The desired result should be:

```
CNAME   SUM(PURCHASES.QUANTITY)
Abel Antunes    1
Berta Borges    5
Carlos Caldas       NULL
Daniela Dimas   2
Elvira Elvas        NULL
```

Hope this clarifies it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT customers.cname,
  SUM(purchases.quantity)
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON customers.CID = purchases.cust
LEFT OUTER JOIN stores ON stores.SID = purchases.Stores
  AND stores.city = 'Porto'
GROUP BY customers.cname;
```

You were trying to get customers, but the left table on your `LEFT JOIN` was `stores`, not `customers`. This way you have the same joins, but with customers on the "left" of your `LEFT JOIN`.

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
However, the result still lists the quantities for all purchases, no matter which store they were bought.
The result should be something like
A 3
B NULL
C 1
D NULL
Although I am getting 
A 13
B 12
C 19
D 20
etc...
This means I am getting the total value of purchased quantities, and not just the purchases in the specific stores!
Any clueS?
Once again thank you!

Comment: Can you add the structure and some sample data to [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com), to make it easier to help you?

Comment: Added in the original question!

Comment: I wanted you to add the original data to sqlfiddle, so i could test it before giving you another query that may not work. Can you do that?

Comment: @user3053043. In the meantime, try replacing the second LEFT JOIN with an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer - the problem is actually solved with an union:

```
(SELECT customers.cname, SUM(purchases.quantity)
FROM customers, purchases, stores
WHERE customers.CID = purchases.cust
AND purchases.Stores = stores.SID
AND stores.city = 'Porto'
GROUP BY customers.cname)
UNION
(SELECT customers.cname, NULL
FROM customers,purchases
WHERE customers.CID = purchases.cust
AND customers.CID NOT IN (SELECT purchases.cust
                              FROM purchases,stores
                              WHERE purchases.Stores = stores.SID
                              AND stores.city = 'Porto'));
```

Thanks anyway!